# About a lambda expression is required to capture a shared pointer that manages a raw pointer.?

Tags: c++, lambda

In C++, a lambda expression is required to capture a shared pointer that manages a raw pointer. Lambda expressions can capture by value or by reference. Capture by value of the shared pointer is equivalent to the copy operation in this context, and copying a shared pointer has an operational overhead, usually regarded as undesired. Why is that? I'm curious

Comment: Why does copying an object have an overhead? or Why is an overhead seen as undesired?

Answer (score 3):

> In C++, a lambda expression is required to capture a shared pointer that manages a raw pointer.

Well, no, but you can do that if you want to.

> Lambda expressions can capture by value or by reference.

True.

> Capture by value of the shared pointer is equivalent to the copy operation in this context

True.

> and copying a shared pointer has an operational overhead

True — a reference count must be incremented and later decremented, and there is a tiny bit of copying of data (not of your pointed-to object, though). This is a small overhead in *time*. There is no overhead in *space* (the reference counter is shared amongst all the linked `shared_ptr`s).

> usually regarded as undesired

That's debatable. Personally I do try not to copy `shared_ptr` when I really don't have to (e.g. within a function), but passing them around to share ownership of a resource is literally the point of their existence, and you shouldn't be frightened of it where doing so makes sense for your program's logic.

Comment: If you just use the reference, the overhead of the copy can be avoided. This overhead can be significant, if the operation is done often. Have a look at the table [here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/memory-and-performance-overhead-of-smart-pointer).

Comment: @ThomasWilde If you capture by reference, then the overhead of the copy is avoided, but then you have to be careful that the original referent is still in scope before the lambda body is executed, which may or may not be guaranteed. It completely depends on what you want to do. As I say, do what makes sense for your program's logic ... and don't worry too much about performance here as it is pretty trivial. I don't care about some random website...

Comment: @ThomasWilde Anyway, you're misinterpreting the page. The table is not comparing copying shared_ptrs, but about different ways to _create_ a resource. The text you're quoting is about the overhead in _space_ (not time), but the reference counter is allocated dynamically and shared by all the linked `shared_ptr`s, and does not take up any more space when you copy it.

Comment: Your answer is right. I just wanted to make an addition. The link I posted is worth a look. It also takes _(time) performance_ into account for creating `smart_ptr`s. If you copy a `smart_ptr` it needs to be created. You can see that there IS an overhead when using `smart_ptr`.  I completely agree that you should not care too much about performance at this level unless you need to.

Comment: @ThomasWilde Oh I thought you were the OP heh

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good answer that is completely correct. As *Asteroids With Wings* said, it depends on what you want to do with your code.

---

I wanted to gain some more insights for myself. I took the following code and took some timings.
The idea is to call a lambda with a reference or with a copy to a `shared_ptr`.
The lambda itself does nothing. The code was compiled with gcc version 9.30 and full optimization (`g++ -O3`).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
  const int num_tests = 10;
  const long long num_calls = 10e8;
  cout << setprecision(12) << fixed;
  cout << "number of lambda calls: \t" << num_calls << endl;
  //---
  auto lambda0 = [](auto /* ptr */) { /*do nothing here*/ };
  auto lambda1 = [](auto & /* ptr */) { /*do nothing here*/ };

  //--- repeat the test 10 times
  double avg_dur = 0.0;
  for (int j = 0; j < num_tests; ++j)
  {
    shared_ptr<int> tmp(new int(j));
    //int *tmp = new int(0);
    auto start = system_clock::now();
    //--- call the lambda with reference
    for (long long i = 0; i < num_calls; ++i)
      lambda1(tmp);
    duration<double> dur = system_clock::now() - start;
    avg_dur += dur.count();
    //delete tmp;
  }
  cout << "average time for reference: \t" << avg_dur / num_tests << " seconds" << endl;

  //--- repeat the test 10 times
  avg_dur = 0.0;
  for (int j = 0; j < num_tests; ++j)
  {
    shared_ptr<int> tmp(new int(j));
    //int *tmp = new int(0);
    auto start = system_clock::now();
    //--- call the lambda with copy
    for (long long i = 0; i < num_calls; ++i)
      lambda0(tmp);
    duration<double> dur = system_clock::now() - start;
    avg_dur += dur.count();
    //delete tmp;
  }
  cout << "average time for copy: \t\t" << avg_dur / num_tests << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

---

**Settings:**

- The lambda is called 1.000.000.000 times.
- The test is repeated 10 times
- The average time of all 10 tests is the final result

---

**Results:**

For a `shared_ptr<int>` you get the following timings:

- 0.000000047600 seconds for reference
- 2.374677258700 seconds for copy

If you replace the smart pointer `shared_ptr<int>` with a raw pointer `int*` the times drop to:

- 0.000000123600 seconds for reference
- 0.000000090500 seconds for copy

---

**Conclusion:**

The overhead for copying a `shared_ptr` *can* be significant compared to passing by reference if you do this a lot of times. But passing by reference cancels the idea of a `shared_ptr` somehow and can be unsafe. Therefore passing a `shared_ptr` by reference should be avoided.

Comment: Note that 2.37 seconds to copy a `shared_ptr` literally a billion times doesn't seem that bad in the grand scheme of things, which is arguably the more useful measurement/conclusion here.

Comment: Totally correct. This is an academic example, that should be relevant for a minority - e.g. guys working in scientific computing area at a university... like me :P